# Rotating map canvas for QGIS 2.8.3 atlas generator?

Tags: qgis, atlas

I have a atlas coverage layer that follows a water network for use with the QGIS atlas generator. I am having issues getting the map canvas rotation to update dynamically with each coverage feature.

What I've done:

- set up a print composer with the map added
- On the generate atlas tab, I checked the box to generate an atlas and chose my coverage layer
- On the map object properties, I checked Parameters controlled by atlas, with 10% margin
- Under map rotation, I clicked the expression drop down, chose edit and entered "Angle" (the name of my field with an angle of rotation).

After generating the atlas and clicking through coverage features, the scale updates, but not the rotation (stays 0). Is there maybe something wrong with my expression?

Comment: Sounds like you've done all the right steps - are you sure the values in the "angle" field are correct?

Answer (score 2):

Probably your problem is solved. In my case I did the same; the box rotation of the map remains in 0º and I thought that I had the same problem as you had but actually the map follow the network.
See the two pictures. In the upper corner, the red square shows how the map is rotating following the line.
[image]

[image]